# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function (Trying to add a RCT Raw Text)

Tags: react-native

This is my error message:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import Home from "./components/Home";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";

import {
    Router,
    Scene
} from "react-native-router-flux";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" style={{paddingTop: 64}}>
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" />
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Chat" />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

The error message is a little cryptic and so I'm having trouble debugging.

Where am I going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused because in Home or Chat you have a string outside < Text >. If not is your case, maybe you have a condition in a return of some component like this:

```
<View>
   {renderSomeThing && 
     <Text>something</Text>
   }
</View>
```

Try:

```
<View>
   {renderSomeThing ? 
     <Text>something</Text>
   : null}
</View>
```

It's posible too you have comments inside jsx codeo or maybe a Text without View parent.